# Target html and javascript to a specific div in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to insert a Trackbuttonto a site where I dont have acces to the html directly. I can paste Javascript and hmtl in a window, and this is outputs the html at the same place in the DOM, and the only way for me to move divs around is with Javascript.

This script and html for a button works, but outputs on the same place in html for all pages. How can I target a specific div with Jquery or vanilla Javascript?

The script and html:

```
<div id="as-root">
</div><script>(function(e,t,n){var r,i=e.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];if(e.getElementById(n))return;r=e.createElement(t);r.id=n;r.src="//apps.aftership.com/all.js";i.parentNode.insertBefore(r,i)})(document,"script","aftership-jssdk")
</script>
<div class="as-track-button" data-tracking-number="12345678" data-counter="true" data-support="true" data-width="400" data-size="large"></div>
```

The div I want to target:

```
li.tracking
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "target" a specific div?

Comment: Are you on the same domain as the parent window? If not, you cannot control the parent with JS at all for security reasons.

Comment: If the div you want doesn't have a unique class or id, you could use :nth-of-type() or :nth-child() selector to get the div that you want, provided they are at the same level in the DOM.

Comment: Could you show us some of the html where the div you're targeting lives?

Comment: I want the div with the tracking number, and the created div from the script to be placed inside my given div in the example.

Comment: the div I want to target are unique. But the script creates a container with divs, and I want this script to appoint this container only to my target div, aswell as the button div in the example.